# Java - Encrypting with RSA key

Tags: java, cryptography, jce

I've been fighting with this issue for a while now. The matter is that I have to send a PEM string to a server, which expects the final step of the following:

- An encryption key of type 3DES o AES-256.
- That key, encrypted with an RSA key.
- That output, encoded in Base64 and in PEM format.

Here's what I got so far:

- Based on the RSA key I've got from the server, I create a Cipher:

  ```
   Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

   rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, (RSAPublicKey) obj);
  ```
- Later, I create an AES key:

  ```
  //IV. 
  byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
  SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
  random.nextBytes(bytes);

  Map<String, byte[]> aes = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();

  aes.put("IV", ConversionUtil.toHex(bytes, 8).getBytes());

  KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");

  keyGen.init(256);
  Key encryptionKey = keyGen.generateKey();

  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 

  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, encryptionKey, new IvParameterSpec(ConversionUtil.toHex(bytes, 8).getBytes()));

  aes.put("key", cipher.doFinal(encryptionKey.getEncoded()));
  ```

Use all that to create the PEM string:

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(StringUtils.repeat("-", 5));
            sb.append("BEGIN PEM file");
            sb.append(StringUtils.repeat("-", 5));
            sb.append("\n");

            sb.append("Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED\n");
            sb.append("DEK-Info: " + "AES-256-CBC" + "," + new String(aes.get("IV")) + "\n");
            sb.append("");
            sb.append(Base64.encode(rsa.doFinal(aes.get("key"))));

            sb.append("\n");
            sb.append(StringUtils.repeat("-", 5));
            sb.append("END PEM file");
            sb.append(StringUtils.repeat("-", 5));
```

And then send that out to the server, which throws the following error:

3936:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:698:

I don't have much more visibility of the error, but I wanted to check if there's anything wrong I might be doing in the process, as it seems that error is associated to the unrecognition of the PEM.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks!

Comment: You are supposed to encrypt using `RSA` and you are encrypting key using `AES`

Comment: Mmm, you might be right, I'm now trying to provide the IV to the RSA Cipher, but I'm getting this error:

   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, (RSAPublicKey) obj, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Parameters not supported

Comment: Check sample [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/BasicRSAexample.htm) you need `RSA` key.

Comment: Yup, I do have that, but I also need to provide an IV since the server will be using it along the RSA key it provides to decrypt the AES/3DES key I made.

Comment: This is not the way to provide IV. IV don't need encryption it can be shared publicly also

Comment: You're right, there's no need for me to encrypt the key with the cipher, I'm just encrypting it with RSA now, but still having issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific error is reported because there should be no spaces between the dashes and the `BEGIN` statement. I don't know about the other issues, but it seems you have some work ahead of you to match the exact input requirements. Make sure you understand *precisely* what is expected, or you may have to try different formats "ad nauseam".

Comment: You just hit the nail. I've managed to make some advances on this, I'm now fighting against the expected carriage returns.
Is there any way I can manually insert these without regards of the actual system configuration? As I'm currently trying with \n and \r, but on the actual output, there are extra ones I didn't insert.
I understand the system has some influence onto how the \n and \r are made.

Comment: The system should not insert carriage returns/line feeds. It's more likely that something is going wrong in your application code. Keep debugging, you will get there eventually :)